# HtmlInputCheckbox onselect event not getting invoked

Tags: c#, asp.net, input, checkbox, onselect

I have a web application which has a gridview with first column as checkbox.

```
<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Select" >
    <HeaderTemplate >
        <asp:CheckBox ID="chkboxSelectAll" runat="server" AutoPostBack="true" />
    </HeaderTemplate>
    <ItemTemplate>
        <input id="chkSelect" name="chkboxSelect" runat="server" type="checkbox" onclick='CheckedChanged'/>          
     </ItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>
```

And also there is a onselect event for input(checkbox) written in code behind where I will highlight the row based on whether the checkbox is checked or not.

My problem is when I check the input checkbox, the onselect event is not getting invoked. Can anyone know whats causing this issue?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Use asp:checkbox with autopostback=true instead of HTML control

Comment: the ItemTemplate has html type checkbox

Comment: When using asp:checkbox I get a weird issue http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20801455/selecting-a-gridview-row-not-working-in-ie-but-works-in-firefox

Comment: then try this link for IE error 
http://forums.asp.net/t/1958701.aspx?Selecting+a+gridview+with+checkbox+as+first+row+not+working+in+IE+but+works+in+Firefox

Comment: I have tried that before. The checkbox value does not persist when I tried the same.

Comment: Obviously the checkbox values will not persist ..you have to handle  postbacks properly and rebind checkboxes on each postback

Answer (score 0):

use this code.
replace html input to asp:checkbox on itemtemplate and assign new event OnCheckedChanged instead of onclick  event

```
<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Select" >
<HeaderTemplate >
         <asp:CheckBox ID="chkboxSelectAll" runat="server" AutoPostBack="true" />
 </HeaderTemplate>
 <ItemTemplate>
         <asp:CheckBox ID="chkSelect" runat="server" AutoPostBack="true" OnCheckedChanged='CheckedChanged'/>
 </ItemTemplate>
```

Comment: When using asp:checkbox I get a weird issue http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20801455/selecting-a-gridview-row-not-working-in-ie-but-works-in-firefox